# Qt how to access resources

Tags: qt, resources, path

Qt Creator give the possibility to attach some resource to the project.
I created in the project directory a folder called: Images. inside i have the file splash1.jpg

I created then the Resources file and attached the file as shown in the following figure:
[image]

Which is now the correct way to access from code such a file?
I tryed

```
QPixmap pixmap( "Images/splash1.jpg" );
QPixmap pixmap( "./Images/splash1.jpg" );
```

but none of them worked.

if i put just ./Images/splash1.jpg work at least if i compile by hand with qmake and make because has the correct path at runtime but no way to make it work within qt creator

Any idea??

Cheers,

Comment: Note: in Qt Designer you can use the context menu on an image in the Resource Browser and choose "Copy Path"; this will include the leading colon necessary (per the answer).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Qt5 resources](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) explains all you need. You have to put the colon before the path in the source tree. You also have placed a prefix, so `:/Images/Images/splash1.jpg`. This will give you a path.
If you need a URL, then use the qrc: scheme.

Comment: i read the documentation but i tought the semicolon was part fo the sentence instead of the path.... ahaah... thanks a lot! :)

Comment: It works for Desktop-Apps! But when I'm working with an iOS-Device (mobile phone), reading the resource fails, with the message: file could not be found

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to load with Qt resources is: `:/Images/Images/splash1.jpg`.

What you could also do, is assign an alias to the resource. This way you don't need the .jpg: `:/Images/splash`

Answer (score 2):

You can use **":/prefix/name of your image"**.