# Including QSettings file in Static QT Release

Tags: qt, static-libraries, qsettings

Is it possible to add a QSettings fileto a static Qt Release? How can I accomplish this, specifically (add as a resource, add something to .pro file, etc.)

Currently my application makes the QSettings file if one does not exist (which it does not on the first build and release).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what OS you need to support? basically format of QSettings file is different and default path, too

Comment: Windows 7. I would imagine we can always clean the path and convert it to native format when pulling from/writing to the settings file, wherever it may live relative to the application directory.

Comment: if you have just one OS, then you can make prebuilt QSettings file and add it to resources and then copy the file at application launch if the file doesn't exist. Or do you have installer for your application?

Comment: Have you build static Qt already?

Comment: You want to add .ini files in the binary? That would be read-only then and changes would have to be stored to the user's settings folder anyway.

Comment: @AlexanderVX, yes I have built static Qt. And no, I'm not saying I want the .ini files in the binary. Is this not something people do? It's looking clearer to me that I just need to provide some values by default to fill the settings file if it is null (on the first start up), so that they don't have to be re-added with each new release copy build or compiler kit change. Thanks all.

Comment: Oh, got it. Your question does not have much to do with static Qt but with putting file to resource. You can locate project.qrc file in resource and simply add your file as resource. And then mind the resource convention for accessing the file.  E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741444/qt-how-to-access-resources